# How to prevent layout rendering when following a link

Tags: layout, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a view that should not be using a layout. 
This is the controller action used :

```
def last
  @video = Video.last
  render layout: false
end
```

When I call the "show" view directly, it works, no layout are used.
Nonetheless, when I call that view by following a link then it actually loads the default layout with my view.

the link is present in a layout :

```
<%= link_to "last video", last_video_path %>
```

and the view :

```
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
  <iframe type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" 
          src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<%= @video %>" >
  </iframe>
</body>
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong ??

Comment: Have you already checked if "last" is really the method called?

Comment: Yes I did, I have even changed the link to : 
    link_to "myLink", :controller => "videos", :action => "last"
So I am sure the last method is call

Comment: I just noticed that if I open my link in a new tab layouts are not rendered so the link is definitely correct, it is just rails that decides for no reason to add a default layout when following a link...

Comment: Honestly I don't know how this is possible... Do you have a before_action which chooses a layout or something?

Comment: I don't... Thank you anyway, I'll keep trying to figure out what goes wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was not working. In my layout, I have in the header :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "NBATopOfTheNight" %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  </head>
  <body>
  ...
```

the line <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> is added by twitter bootstrap and is responsible for rendering my views even when I specify no rendering.
Deleting this line make my project works :-)